# Grails, findBy don't work with national characters like 'å','ä','ö'

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For instance, Supplier.findByName('Röde Orm') returns null even though this name exists in the field "SearchName" in table "Supplier".
Is this correct or do I have to do some reconfiguration of grails?

Comment: Is the search name column nvarchar?

Comment: No, it's varchar.

Comment: What is the underlying database?

Comment: You need to use nvarchar if you want support for languages other than English.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL Server. But I have used swedish character in the database all time and used varchar. They always display correct in the form but findBySearchName will not work. But I may be wrong about this. I just noticed that if there is a space in the word the findBySearchname fails. So the text "Rode Orm" also fails. So there is a chance that this doesn't depend on national charaters. What do you say?

Comment: I was wrong again the word "Röde" also fails so it seems like it doesn't like the swedish character and it don't like space either.

Comment: Space in the middle of the search word was only a problem when using  Supplier.findBySearchName(URLEncoder.encode(mill, "UTF-8")) If I used Supplier.findBySearchName(mill) it was no problem with the "space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now the problem disappeared. I don't know why I got the problem in the beginning but I know that the URLEncoder.encode was completely wrong to use here but I never thought about that and after doing some corrections in the database, still using varchar, things started to work but not until I removed the URLEncoder call.